# ExpressionEngine Display Section Title Once if Channel Entries Present

Tags: if-statement, expressionengine, channel

I'm wondering if there a simpler way to achieve this, that cuts down on the number of queries submitted to the server:

I have a section on the home page where users can purchase tickets to an event. I don't have ticketed events that often, so I only want that section to display when tickets are available.

The way I've been doing it is like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="ticketed_events" limit=1}
<h2>Purchase Tickets</h2>
{/exp:channel:entries}
{exp:channel:entries channel="ticketed_events"}
{event_title} - {ticket_price}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I have to do it twice so that the title only displays the one time, instead of once per entry. That seems a little awkward, having to send two queries to the server like that. Is that really the only way to do it?

ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="ticketed_events"}
{if count == 1}<h2>Purchase Tickets</h2>{/if}
{event_title} - {ticket_price}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Without trying that should do it, otherwise try `{if {count} == 1}`

Comment: I always assumed count to be a function that returned the number of entries in the found set – in some database scripting languages, it is. I knew the answer would be staring me in the face. Thanks!

Comment: There are (somewhat confusingly) 4 different "counts" documented: absolute_count, absolute_results, count, total_results. Each is useful in certain circumstances.